# Fast PWM - ATTiny2313 on OC0A (PB2)

Tags: c, atmel, avrdude, attiny

Im trying to send a PWM signal on the OC0A (PB2) with ATTiny2313 but for some reason nothing is happen on Port B2. My code shows as following:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

/**
 * Initialize fast pwm on PB2 (OC0A)
 */
void pwmInit() {
    // Setup the output for PWM
    DDRB |= (1 << DDB2);

    // Set Timer/Counter0 prescaler to clock/1.
    // At 8MHz this is 8MHz.
    TCCR0B |= (1 << CS00);

    // Set to 'Fast PWM' mode
    TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM01) | (1 << WGM00);

    // Clear OC0A output on compare match, upwards counting.
    TCCR0A |= (1 << COM0A1);

    // If the value '128' is reached, the PWM signal will set to LOW
    OCR0A=128; // 128 = 50% duty cycle
}

void setup() {
    pwmInit();

    DDRB |= (1 << DDB0); // Setup the Output fon port B0
}

int main(void) {
    setup();

    while(1) {
        PORTB |= (1<<PB0);
        _delay_ms(500);

        PORTB &= ~(1<<PB0);
        _delay_ms(500);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The LED on PB0 is blinking, but on oscilloscope is no PWM signal (on PB2) is shown and the led on PB2 is still off. Do i have missconfigured the MCU?

Similar code on ATTiny13A is still working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i accidentally selected a wrong MCU architecture (in my case attiny13 instead of attiny2313) on project creation in Code::Blocs. I solved this by changing the configuration in ".cbp" and changed any attiny13 to attiny2313 (in my case in environment, compiler and linker config).

How i detected this: on trying to set

```
DDRD |= (1<<DD5);
```

to test OC0B instead of OC0A as PWM output the compiler error is occured like DDRD can not be found.